# Cooking: Is it possible to combine Primus Omnilite Ti Stove with Soto Stormbreaker Bottle?

Tags: cooking, stoves, ultralight, liquid-fuel-stoves

Is it possible to use a `Primus Omnilite Ti` stove with a `Soto Stormbreaker` bottle?

The Soto Bottle has several advantages over the Primus pendant (e.g. pressure indicator, power regulator, etc.) which is why I would like to combine advantages of both.

Comment: I suspect you won't get an answer easily unless someone has actually tried it. It would depend on the width of the mouth of the bottles and the threading inside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both manufacturers would probably say no, because of liability worries (e.g if the threads seemed compatible but you didn't get a good seal, leaked fuel, and started a fire - they think of worst case scenarios).  The threads on many fuel bottles are the same, and in that case it should be compatible if both are (i) designed to be pressurised and (ii) have the same surface to accept a seal (probably just a flat for an O-ring)

However looking up the Soto, it's not the *bottle* you need, but the hose assembly that screws into it - the bottle cap if you like, and that's another matter.  In many designs, such as my MSR, the hose comes out of the pump/cap assembly - quite possibly in both of these as well.  This part needs to seal, so you need the same interface between the two.  I can't see detailed pictures of them disassembled, let alone dimensioned drawings, but from photos there's a chance - and only a chance.

The Primus has a  power regulator valve as well, so the Soto gives you the ability to run off gas canisters (butane/propane) as well as liquid fuels;  the only real benefit the Primus offers for its higher price point is the lower weight, and you need to be sure to compare like with like (e.g. with/without bottle, which is a lot of the weight)

Comment: Bottle could well be slightly different - Soto is USA (imperial measurements), Primus is European (metric) - mix imperial and metric gauges and it won't seal under pressure, even if it looks and feels like they have.

Comment: @bob1 US engineering can go either way.  I've worked with a lot of American-made metric stuff.  And inch-denominated pipe fittings are used internationally.  MSR (American) [apparently copied Sigg](https://www.practicalmachinist.com/vb/general/screw-thread-identification-165864/) but the thread is a 3/4" pipe thread (which is a lot bigger than 3/4" because if was the thread used with thick-walled 3/4" bore pipe)

Comment: ... But anyway (i) many, not all, are the same, and (ii) I don't think it matters too much.  The metric/imperial distinction may come in again on the unthreaded  hose fitting.